# How to check if camera supports auto-focus on Android with CameraX?

Tags: android, androidx, autofocus, android-camerax

Currently I'm using the [CameraX](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax) library in my Android project. I'd like to decide programmatically if the given camera instance supports auto-focus. How can I get this info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could solve it by extending the [CameraCharacteristics](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics) class in the following way:

```
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics

val CameraCharacteristics.hasAutoFocus: Boolean
  get() = get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_MAX_REGIONS_AF) != 0
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite get it. (camera.cameraInfo as Camera2CameraInfoImpl).cameraCharacteristicsCompat.get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_MAX_REGIONS_AF) seems to work, but it doesn't feel right. Can you tell me how to get this information properly please?

Comment: Try to get the cameraCharacteristics object from the cameraManager like this:
"cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId)". You can instantiate the cameraManager like this: "context.getSystemService(CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager".